# List View Item Scroll able vertical

Tags: android, listview, scroll

Currently I'm using `ListView` and it's working fine. But I have text in a `ListView` that is like a paragraph and I just want to show those 2 lines of text and make the rest of the text scrollable, but I'm having an issue that if I make the `TextView` scrollable inside of the `ListView`, then the `TextView` get the focus of its parent (`ListView`) and won't let it be scrolled.

So can I achieve this scrollable `TextView` functionality that won't disturb the scrolling property of the `ListView`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is Impossible yet way to do things are may b difficult. Directly this thing can`t be achieved but indirectly yes it can be achieved, and yes i achieved.
how did i achieve is a bit complex but yes will share that how did i achieve.

In a `ListView` when i click on `Textview` i block the Touch mode of the listView so that their toch method don't intercept each other, and that can be done by using  `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);`
this block the `TouchListener` of the parent (`ListView`).

Now when click on `TextView` i allow its touch listener and also `setMovementMethod`()
but for Movement i made a custom class and Class is Following

```
public class myScrollMethod extends ScrollingMovementMethod {

    @Override
    public void onTakeFocus(TextView widget, Spannable text, int dir) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onTakeFocus(widget, text, dir);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(TextView widget, Spannable buffer,
            int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
            for (int i = 0, scrollAmount = getScrollAmount(widget); i < scrollAmount; i++) {
                down(widget, buffer);
            }
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
            for (int i = 0, scrollAmount = getScrollAmount(widget); i < scrollAmount; i++) {
                up(widget, buffer);
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onKeyDown(widget, buffer, keyCode, event);
        }
    }

    private int getScrollAmount(TextView widget) {
        final int visibleLineCount = (int) ((1f * widget.getHeight()) / widget
                .getLineHeight());
        int scrollAmount = visibleLineCount - 1;
        if (scrollAmount < 1) {
            scrollAmount = 1;
        }
        return scrollAmount;
    }


}
```

After that when i click on parent i enable the TouchIntercepter of the parent set true and that get hold on its parent and start scrolling.

By this way i have successfully achieved this requirement

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do this in the following way:

Into the getView method of the ListAdapter obtain the TextView object of the line, and write

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       v.getParent().getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
       return false ;
   }
});
```

when you will touch the TextView, take control of the scrolling

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve really is impossible. How can the OS know that you are trying to scroll the list vs the list row paragraph? You would essentially need to scroll to the bottom of the list row paragraph before the actual list itself could scroll. This is confusing to the user, and not common UX.

I would suggest you look into [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). It allows you to have collapsed versions of each row, in your case just 2 lines of text for each list row. When the user taps on the row, it could expand to the full paragraph form, and the list would be scrollable the whole time. There are plenty of tutorials you should be able to find online.